# Are there any methods for players spending their victory points?

Tags: pathfinder-2e

In Pathfinder 2e one of the alternative rulesets is [Victory points](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=1189). Players gain these points by rolling success/critical succcess and lose them via failure. I found the idea quite interesting though I kind of want to provide my players with a way to spend said points. Are there any guidelines for doing such a thing? Something akin to fame from PF 2e?

Comment: It looks like the intended design of the system is just a way to track success or failure towards a big goal that would comprise of many checks over time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## There’s Been a Misunderstanding

Victory Points are intended to be used to measure progress in specific subsystems, such as the [Research Subsystem](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=1205) where they are named Research Points or the [Infiltration Subsystem](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=1221) where they are Infiltration Points. They are not awarded generally to players outside of subsystems like these.